# Comparing Duplicate Samples

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with set of 1200 individual cases in duplicate in one column for a total of 2400. i.e. A1.1234567_10, A1.1234567_20, There are multiple columns that I would like to compare such that each duplicate pair has the same or discrepant result in each column. columns contain factors How can I make it so that it can give a logical for my factors. I want to select each case by its ID (i.e A1.1234567) that matches _10 and _20:

EXAMPLE
(one row of data frame)

```
A1.1234567_10 NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL

A1.1234567_20 NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL ABNORMAL NORMAL
```

Id like the output to look like this(new data frame)

```
A1.1234567 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

And this would repeat for all of the samples down the column by unique ID number comparing _10 and _20

Comment: YOu may need to check for `duplicated`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse option:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(ID = c("A1.1234567_10", "A1.1234567_20"), 
                     var1 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                     var2 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                     var3 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                     var4 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                     var5 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                     var6 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL"), 
                     var7 = c("NORMAL", "ABNORMAL"), 
                     var8 = c("NORMAL", "NORMAL")), 
                .Names = c("ID", "var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8"), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

# separate group variable from observation label
df_tidy <- df %>% separate(ID, c('ID', 'obs'), sep = '_')

df_tidy
#>           ID obs   var1   var2   var3   var4   var5   var6     var7   var8
#> 1 A1.1234567  10 NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL   NORMAL NORMAL
#> 2 A1.1234567  20 NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL NORMAL ABNORMAL NORMAL

df_tidy %>% 
    select(-obs) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise_all(lift(`==`))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 9
#>           ID  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6  var7  var8
#>        <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1 A1.1234567  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: I was trying this exactly with my own data frame and i keep getting the error:  Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: operator needs two arguments.

Comment: This approach assumes groups of two rows. If you have more, maybe use `summarise_all(reduce, \`==\`)`. If you have one-row groups, some extra though may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with `tidyverse` (credits to @alistaire's `dput`):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID = str_extract(ID, ".+(?=_)")) %>%
  summarize_all(funs(dim(table(.)) == 1))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 1 x 9
          ID  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6  var7  var8
       <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 A1.1234567  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: this gave me the first part correct in terms of allowing me to combine the samples but somehow every single one is now FALSE when i know that not to be the case